# How can I make a button redirect my page to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying the following:

```
<form action="/home" class="inline">
    <button class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>
</form>
```

It seems to work but it goes to the page "/home?"

Is there a better way for me to make a button inside a form make the page go to a new location?

Comment: A form element can only take you to other pages within the same site. If you want to redirect to other websites, you need to use JavaScript's location.href or similar.

Comment: $(location).prop('href', '/your_path');

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Just add an `onclick` event to the `button`:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';" id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>
```

But you shouldn't really have it inline like that, instead, put it in a JS block and give the `button` an ID:

```
<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: <button class="btn-lg btn-success" formaction="ContactUs.html">ACCEPT</button>

Comment: Do I need to have a form tag in this HTML that describes the method and submit action?

Comment: @Himansz Not if you're not going to submit the form. If it's a simple re-direction then you don't need a form.

Comment: does this work on mobile too?

Comment: How can i send POST data when calling location.href

Comment: why not have it inline?

Comment: @NabeelKhan Old question, but if you need it : One advantage of not having it inline is that you can then put it in a JS resource file that is loaded from the server, which allows you to implement Content Security Policies (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: Just for the next person that stumbles upon this: without a http:// or https:// in front of the link, my browser treats it as a relatvie path. So just add that if you're facing the same issue

Answer (score 64):

try

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='b.php'">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Boostrap Submit and Cancel Buttons - Do this;                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='somewhere.php'"> Cancel </button>

Comment: for those using bootstrap, might want to route to a function `onclick="myfunc(e)"` and add `e.preventDefault()` in myfunc to disable default button behavior.

Answer (score 25):

Use this:

```
 <button onclick="window.location='page_name.php';" value="click here" />
```

Basically you are using javascript snippet to redirect and onclick event of the button to trigger it.

Comment: Hope you will find this useful. Please try this: `<td colspan="4"><input type="button" name="back" onclick="parent.location='contacts.php'" value="Back to List" class="McElieButton2"></td>`

Comment: Works better than `location.href` right now

Answer (score 12):

Just another variation:

```
    <body>
    <button name="redirect" onClick="redirect()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect()
    {
    var url = "http://www.(url).com";
    window.location(url);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: window.location is not a function!
Use this: 
setTimeout('window.location.href="url"', 0);

or JQuery:
$(location).attr('href',url);

Comment: This doesnt work, instead use window.location.href="http...";

Comment: @GeneralKimi Why timeout?

Answer (score 6):

you could do so:

```
<button onclick="location.href='page'">
```

you could change the action attribute of the form on click the button:

```
<button class="float-left submit-button" onclick='myFun()'>Home</button>

<script>
myFun(){
$('form').attr('action','new path');
}
</script>
```