# Freemarker actions: how to navigate back to home page while form action points to methods

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I've written an app in `dropwizard` that lets you view and edit information on a database.  In order to call the methods for this from my resource class, I annotated them with @Path("/path/to/method").  I then set the form actions in the `Freemarker` templates to these paths so these methods can be used.  Here's what I mean:

The Resource method:

```
@Path("/home")
public class MyResource

    @POST
    @Path("/update/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void updateProfile(@PathParam("id") int id, @FormParam("name") String name) {
            Profile profile = new Profile(id, name);
            manager.newProfile(id, profile);
    }
```

And the freemarker form:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/update/${profile.id}" target="_blank">

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="${profile.name}">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

This has worked fine, but I'd like to be able to navigate back to `/home` on clicking the submit button.  I've tried using `location.href` on the button and pointing it back to the home page:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'localhost:8080/home';" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562577/how-can-i-make-a-button-redirect-my-page-to-another-page), but it just opened a new tab for update(which of course, was blank.

Comment: You need to change location after the post is submitted.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: How can I elaborate on not clear question? Seems you can't do what I have suggested that's why you asking me for the elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have controller method on `/home` you can add a form submitting it on same page with `_self` target:

```
<form method="post" action="/home" target="_self">
  <button type="submit">Home</button>
</form>
```