# How to script a link that will open another page and select something in that page

Tags: javascript, class, onclick

I have a page (let's call this page2.html) that has a long list of `<a href>` links in it, each one opening an image in an iframe on that page.

I would now like to create a preceding page that will act as an introduction (let's call it page1.html).  I need to create a link on page1 that opens page2 AND opens an image in the iframe on page2 (or alternatively open page2 and select one of the `<a href>` on page2).

I have tried the following

```
<a href="page2.html" onclick="window.open('image.png','iframe-name')">
```

but this does not work for me as I believe it is looking for the iframe on page1 (not page2).

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Addendum:**

I have now found some code that solves part of my problem.  By putting the images in their own html pages and adding a little JavaScript in both the image pages and page2 (the one with the iframe) I am now able to force the image pages to appear in the iframe (code below).

The missing piece now is to highlight (add a class) the relevant anchor to show which image is being shown.

When I am on page2 and click one of the anchors I use the following to add a 'selected' class to the anchor:

```
var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
function show(obj) {
if (selected.length) selected[0].className = '';
obj.className = "selected";
}
```

How can I add a class to an object on page2 when loading it from page1?

Alternatively is there a way to add a class to an object on page2 based on what is begin displayed in the iframe on the same page?

Here's the javascript I'm using to load a page into an iframe:

This goes in the index page (my page2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
var data=location.search;
if(data) {
    data=location.search.substring(1); // remove the '?'
    frames[0].location = data;
    }
};
</script>
```

And this goes in each of the image pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top == self) {
    location.href = 'index.html?' + self.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with nothing but an anchor tag. You will need to pass something like a get string parameter to the 2nd page and have some code there that can use it to "select" what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562577/how-can-i-make-a-button-redirect-my-page-to-another-page

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. As @gforce301 has mentioned you can use anchor and scroll or do something else with the help of script in inside that second page. 

But if you are doing this thing or planning to do this regularly I suggest check chrome extension development.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  @gforce301 do you have any examples of passing a parameter to the 2nd page and using that to 'select'?