# How to redirect a web page with help of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a>
    <div class="grid__item theme-1">
      <button class="action"></button>
      <button class="particles-button">Home</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

In this Effect applied how can I redirect it after the effect completed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Please show some effort into the question, there is a lot of answers to the same question. One usage is: `onclick="location.href='http://google.com';"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please start your question with a question - that's why it is called a question. An uncommented piece of code does not really help the community to understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a button redirect my page to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562577/how-can-i-make-a-button-redirect-my-page-to-another-page)

Answer (score -1):

Just add an `onclick` event to the `button`:

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'www.anysite.com';" id="buttonID" class="particles-button" >Home</button>
```

and other way is

```
<button class="particles-button" id="buttonID" >Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.anysite.com";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use a `<a>` tag for webpage indirect, because:

1. It doesn't require JavaScript
2. It is easier to implement accessibility features
3. It makes the HTML code more readable

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a>
    <div class="grid__item theme-1">
      <a href="https://www.w3docs.com/" class="button">Click Here</a>
      <button class="particles-button">Home</button>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://google.com'">Go to link</button>
```