# change code create account to open external ink

Tags: php, button

Here I have code in our website template to create new account:

```
<button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create account')) ?></span></button>
```

I would like to rewrite this code to open an external link, e.g. google after clicking. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use javascript to redirect with `onclick`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562577/how-can-i-make-a-button-redirect-my-page-to-another-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a button redirect my page to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562577/how-can-i-make-a-button-redirect-my-page-to-another-page)